# Render HTML content on A4 pages

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I have text content with over 50,000 words. I have to separate it page by page in A4 size but the text is overflowing after the 1st page.
I need to preview the HTML content (on browser, before printing) on A4 page. Issue is that I am unable to keep track of the page height. So, when page ended, some of the content goes outside the page.

Is there some way I can render dynamic HTML content on A4 pages?

Comment: HTML isn't a "paged" medium; the best you're going to be able to do is "print" it and preview the printing with the page size set to A4.

Comment: If "some of the content goes outside the page", this would seem to imply that you're trying to force page-layout-style formatting on the HTML, instead of just letting the HTML "flow" naturally.  You shouldn't be forcing this.

Comment: I have paragraphs, headings, and multiple other HTML elements. And the required functionality is to export HTML content into Book Format (PDF on A4 size pages). But before that, I want to preview the content. So, I have written CSS to represent a A4 page, and displayed content there. Issue is that, if current element to be rendered occupies space greater than the remaining page space, it just overflows, or move the whole element to next page. But I want it to adjust dynamically..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css, like below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @page 
            {
                size: a4 portrait;
                margin: 15pt 15pt; 
            }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        your long text ...
    </body>
</html>
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page
.

For closer control, use the `break-inside` CSS property; see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside

```
<div style="break-inside:auto;">
...
</div>
```

Comment: @Muha if you like the answer, please accept it (push the checkmark). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by using CSS media queries and setting the page size to A4 dimensions. You can define a @media print query in your CSS and set the page size, margins, and other styles specifically for printing. This will allow you to preview the content as it would appear on A4 pages in the browser before printing.

Example: (A4 width, height and margin)

```
@media print {
  body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    margin: 20mm;
 }
```

}

You can apply this CSS to your HTML document and then use the browser's print preview feature to see how the content is distributed across A4 pages.